# Python webscrape not resolving some hyperlinks

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Scraping some webpages I don't get the same source as when inspecting in a browser. Hyperlinks that are actual hyperlinks when looking at the source in a browser, turn up as `{url}`. Below is example code for an example page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
page = requests.get("https://www.mckinsey.com/search?q=iot")
soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'item title-link'})
```

If inspecting the soup element on the last line in the browser it is a full url. If inspecting it in the requests version it just says `{url}`, and getting the soup object just comes up empty.

Comment: You might have to use `ghost.py` for this, since url is being generated by javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This portal uses `JavaScript` to get data from server and put on page.

Using `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox you can see that `javaScript` sends `POST` request with `JSON` parameters and it gets all data as JSON. If you get it then you have all as dictionary.

```
import requests

params = {
    'q': 'iot',
    'page': '1',
    'app': '',
    'sort': 'default',
    'ignoreSpellSuggestion': 'false',
}

url = 'https://www.mckinsey.com/services/ContentAPI/SearchAPI.svc/search'

for page in range(1, 3):

    params['page'] = str(page)

    r = requests.post(url, json=params)

    data = r.json() 

    print()
    print("data['data'].keys():\n", data['data'].keys())
    print()      
    print(' currentPage:', data['data']['currentPage'])
    print('  totalPages:', data['data']['totalPages'])
    print('totalResults:', data['data']['totalResults'])
    print()

    print("data['data']['results'][0].keys():\n", data['data']['results'][0].keys())
    print()

    for item in data['data']['results']:
        print(item['title'])
        print(item['url'])
        print('---')
```

Result:

```
data['data'].keys():
 dict_keys(['totalResults', 'totalPages', 'currentPage', 'recommendations', 'results'])

 currentPage: 1
  totalPages: 17
totalResults: 166

data['data']['results'][0].keys():
 dict_keys(['title', 'subtitle', 'imageurl', 'dek', 'tag', 'mimetype', 'url'])

Taking the pulse of enterprise <b>IoT</b>
https://www.mckinsey.com/global-themes/internet-of-things/our-insights/taking-the-pulse-of-enterprise-iot
---
An executive&#39;s guide to the Internet of Things
https://www.mckinsey.com/business-functions/digital-mckinsey/our-insights/an-executives-guide-to-the-internet-of-things
---
Internet of Things | Internet of Things
https://www.mckinsey.com/global-themes/internet-of-things/how-we-help-clients
---
Unlocking the potential of the Internet of Things
https://www.mckinsey.com/business-functions/digital-mckinsey/our-insights/the-internet-of-things-the-value-of-digitizing-the-physical-world
---
Internet of Things
https://www.mckinsey.com/global-themes/internet-of-things/our-insights
---
Six ways CEOs can promote cybersecurity in the <b>IoT</b> age
https://www.mckinsey.com/global-themes/internet-of-things/our-insights/six-ways-ceos-can-promote-cybersecurity-in-the-iot-age
---
What&#39;s new with the Internet of Things?
https://www.mckinsey.com/industries/semiconductors/our-insights/whats-new-with-the-internet-of-things
---
How can we recognize the real power of the Internet of Things?
https://www.mckinsey.com/business-functions/digital-mckinsey/our-insights/how-can-we-recognize-the-real-power-of-the-internet-of-things
---
Making sense of Internet of Things platforms
https://www.mckinsey.com/business-functions/digital-mckinsey/our-insights/making-sense-of-internet-of-things-platforms
---
Partnerships, scale, and speed: The hallmarks of a successful <b>IoT</b> strategy
https://www.mckinsey.com/industries/financial-services/our-insights/partnerships-scale-and-speed
---

data['data'].keys():
 dict_keys(['totalResults', 'totalPages', 'currentPage', 'recommendations', 'results'])

 currentPage: 2
  totalPages: 17
totalResults: 166

data['data']['results'][0].keys():
 dict_keys(['title', 'subtitle', 'imageurl', 'dek', 'tag', 'mimetype', 'url'])

THE INTERNET OF THINGS: MAPPING THE VALUE BEYOND THE HYPE
https://www.mckinsey.com/~/media/mckinsey/business%20functions/mckinsey%20digital/our%20insights/the%20internet%20of%20things%20the%20value%20of%20digitizing%20the%20physical%20world/unlocking_the_potential_of_the_internet_of_things_executive_summary.ashx
---
The future of connectivity: Enabling the Internet of Things
https://www.mckinsey.com/global-themes/internet-of-things/our-insights/the-future-of-connectivity-enabling-the-internet-of-things
---
THE INTERNET OF THINGS: MAPPING THE VALUE BEYOND THE HYPE
https://www.mckinsey.com/~/media/mckinsey/business%20functions/mckinsey%20digital/our%20insights/the%20internet%20of%20things%20the%20value%20of%20digitizing%20the%20physical%20world/the-internet-of-things-mapping-the-value-beyond-the-hype.ashx
---
Insurers need to plug into the Internet of Things – or risk falling behind
https://www.mckinsey.com/~/media/mckinsey/industries/financial%20services/our%20insights/european%20insurance%20practice%20report%20on%20internet%20of%20things/mckinsey%20-%20insurers%20need%20to%20plug%20into%20the%20internet%20of%20things%20or%20risk%20falling%20behind.ashx
---
Security in the Internet of Things
https://www.mckinsey.com/industries/semiconductors/our-insights/security-in-the-internet-of-things
---
Semiconductors
https://www.mckinsey.com/~/media/mckinsey/industries/semiconductors/our%20insights/mckinsey%20on%20semiconductors%20issue%206%20-%20spring%202017/mck%20on%20semiconductors_issue%206_2017.ashx
---
Internet of Things: Opportunities and challenges for semiconductor companies
https://www.mckinsey.com/industries/semiconductors/our-insights/internet-of-things-opportunities-and-challenges-for-semiconductor-companies
---
THE INTERNET OF THINGS: MAPPING THE VALUE BEYOND THE HYPE
https://www.mckinsey.com/~/media/mckinsey/business%20functions/mckinsey%20digital/our%20insights/the%20internet%20of%20things%20the%20value%20of%20digitizing%20the%20physical%20world/unlocking_the_potential_of_the_internet_of_things_full_report.ashx
---
A new Internet of Things platform and business | Digital McKinsey
https://www.mckinsey.com/business-functions/digital-mckinsey/how-we-help-clients/a-new-internet-of-things-platform-and-business
---
Video meets the Internet of Things
https://www.mckinsey.com/industries/high-tech/our-insights/video-meets-the-internet-of-things
---
```

Comment: This is great! I am having trouble finding the SearchAPI url, which you found, in DevTools, though.

Comment: load oryginal page, go to DevTools -> Network -> XHR and reload page.

Comment: Thanks! Your example above gets just the first 10 of the 166 results. How to get the rest?

Comment: see `'page': '1'`, in `params` - probably if you use `'page': '2',` then you get next 10 results.

Comment: I added `for` loop which loads with `'page': '1'` and `'page': '2'`. There is `data['data']['totalPages']` which you could use with `for` or `while`